# randomness in array program in c randomness in array

Tags: c

Let's say that the 'randomness' of an array is equal to the number of swap one needs to do in order to have the array as completely sorted.

I want to write a program that would take in a sorted input array and as output would return an array with maximum 'randomness'.

Please help.

Comment: Generally questions end with a question mark: `?`

Comment: Just return the reverse-sorted array.

Comment: Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how you define "swap".

For example, if your array was `[1,2,3,4,5]` and swaps must be between adjacent numbers, then the array with maximum "randomness" would be the reverse `[5,4,3,2,1]`. However, if swaps can be between any two numbers, then the array with maximum "randomness" would be any array that takes `(array length)-1` swaps to sort, such as `[5,1,4,2,3]`

Comment: Which sorting algorithm are you using?

Comment: quick sort needs 5 swaps

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible arrays that require the maximum number of swaps to sort. For example, take the numbers 1 through 5.

2,3,4,5,1

5,4,3,2,1

Both require five swaps to produce the sorted array, because all elements are out of position.